# Prove that ln(n) is not a Cauchy Sequence?

Tags: logarithms, cauchy-sequences

Show from the definition of a Cauchy Sequence that Xn=ln(n) is not a Cauchy Series

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Yeah it does thanks, I’ll close the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove that there is some epsilon > 0 such that for any N > 0 there is some n and m with |ln(n/m)| >= epsilon

for example, is you take epsilon = 1 and n=m+1, then the inequality is satisfied after some index N

Comment: How/why do you get ln(n/m) I don’t understand where this comes from?

Comment: ln n - ln m = ln (n/m)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\log n$ is Cauchy.

For given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $n_0$ s.t. for $m\ge n\ge n_0$

$|\log m-\log n| <\epsilon$.

Consider $m=kn$, where $k$ is a positive integer.

Then

$|\log m-\log n|= |\log (m/n)|=|\log k| <\epsilon$.

For $k$ large enough, a contradiction (Why?)

Comment: becuase it fails eventually for some epsilon, for instance epsilon = 1 will fail after k=e

Comment: Yes. Or a bit more general, since $\log k$ in not bounded above it will fail for any $\epsilon >0$ choosing $k$ large enough. Cheers.